# How can I calculate the axis of rotation around this discrete 3D spiral and how much would I need to rotate it to meet a certain condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, rotations

[In a previous question, I asked about calculating the center of a discrete 3D spiral and eventually got a working solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4282732) Now I'm trying to find the axis line it creates and how much I would need to spin it so the 2nd cube moves to where the first cube was. I'll explain what I mean by that more towards the end. First, some background.

### Background

I'm more of an artist than a mathematician so bare with me. I have taken Calc 2 in university but that was 8 years ago and we never did anything with vectors or linear algebra.


Say we have a discrete spiral like in the video below. It is formed by placing a 1 meter cube at the origin. Then, the next cube has some translation, rotation, and a scaling factor that is between 0 and 1. Then this process repeats but the translation and scaling vectors are scaled down each time. It eventually comes to a point that I can now calculate with some code thanks to some brilliant people.

[A typical spiral](https://i.imgur.com/h0Skbd9.gifv)

[This might help you understand how it's formed](https://i.imgur.com/UwgdDsN.gifv)

### Questions

1. I'm now trying to find the red line in the image below so I can spin it around that axis. I'm guessing two of the three rotation axes will be used to put the line into the correct orientation and then the third will be used to sweep it around the axis. My software (Blender) can handle different rotation modes (Quaternion, various Euler rotations, and "axis angle"). [Blender is free](https://www.blender.org/download/) and I don't mind sharing the file if helps you understand the problem. Just let me know.

[The red line is what I'm trying to find. This one was placed by hand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e0RA.png)

2. How much would I need to spin it? Since I'm scaling each cube down by say $k$, if I scale the whole spiral up by $1/k$ from the center of the spiral, then the 2nd cube become 1 meter (the 1st cube's original size). Then, if I spin it in the right amount, it's position would go to the 1st cube's original position. The 2nd cube basically moves to where the 1st cube was and matches it's scale and orientation. All the other cubes would do a similar thing. The $nth$ cube would move to the $n - 1$ cube. If it's done at a specific rate (which I already know the formula to), it'll make a really cool looping effect. These are often only done along [one](https://www.instagram.com/p/CULHYoXjzdb/) or [two](https://www.instagram.com/p/CDREW25H7Aq/) dimensions since the 3D solution is so difficult to calculate. Hence me being here. If I can get an answer, I'll share this with the art community and become a legend. I'm hoping the answers to these two questions will fix a problem I'm having.

I should note that I'm assuming that above is true. It makes intuitive sense to me since the works like that in 2D. And I can already kinda do it but it doesn't work quite right. See below.

### Problem I'm having

What I'm currently doing is close but doesn't work perfectly. I thought I would be able to use the starting rotation but it makes a sharp transition (see below). Instead of spinning it around the axis, I'm taking the rotation values that generated the spiral (the rotation vector of the 2nd cube) and subtracting them from the rotation vector of the spiral center. The 2nd cube goes back to the first which is good but doesn't do so *smoothly*. Smoothness is mission critical to making these loops feel nice.

[An example of the sharp transition. It appears to bounce. Not ideal.](https://i.imgur.com/V9bsJwN.gifv)

### Update

[I've made a video to help explain what I trying to do in case there is any confusion.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0w2BZJDUmw) I think the amount I need to rotate it in, is the original rotation amount but it needs to be converted so rotating only 1 axis (the axis around the center of the spiral) undoes the original rotation.

I'm not sure how to tag this question. Feel free to edit it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found a solution thanks to u/1184x1210Forever on Reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/askmath/comments/qtde80)

And it's surprisingly simple. If I convert the rotation matrix on the Parameters object from XYZ Euler to Axis-Angle ($W+XYZ$ where $XYZ$ is a 3D Vector), then the axis that runs through the spiral is that 3D Vector and the amount I need to rotate to undo the original rotation becomes $-W$.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. Does the video look correct now?

Comment: It does. It's perfect, seamless and smooth, and the solution ends up being a natural extension of the 2D solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand what you are doing.

But it sounds like, you have some starting position $\mathbf u_0$, and some starting vector $\mathbf v_0$.

$\mathbf u_1 = \mathbf u_0 + \mathbf v_0$

We then tweak $\mathbf v_0$ scaling it smaller and giving it a change in direction.
this is a linear transformation $\mathbf v_1 = A\mathbf v_0$

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a&-b &0\\b&a&0\\0&0&c\end{bmatrix}$ would be an example matrix $A$

The coefficients $a,c$ control the scaling factors.  $a,c$ are negative if you want the spiral to be shrinking toward infinity.  $a$ is be the scaling on the radius of the spiral, $c$ is the scaling along the axis of the spiral.)

We could use matrices similar to $A$ if you wanted a different axis of rotation.  There would then be a corresponding eigenvector for this different axis.

$\mathbf v_{n+1} = A\mathbf v_{n}\\
\mathbf v_{n} = A^n v_{0}$

$\mathbf u_{n+1} = \mathbf u_n + \mathbf v_n$

In stead of moving in steps, we could model this as a differential equation.

$\mathbf v' = A\mathbf v\\
\mathbf v(t) = e^{At} \mathbf v_0 = \begin{bmatrix} e^{at}\cos bt & -e^{at} \sin bt&0\\ e^{at}\sin bt &e^{at}\cos bt & 0\\0&0&e^{ct} \end{bmatrix}\mathbf v_0\\
\mathbf u(t) = A^{-1}e^{At}\mathbf v_0 + u_0$

And the point where this spiral collapses to will be:

$\lim_\limits{t\to \infty} \mathbf u(t) = A^{-1}\mathbf v_0 + \mathbf u_0$

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm able to calculate where the spiral collapse already. I did something similar. But the spiral seems to have some sort of axis line coming out of it. No matter how I configure the spiral, I can always look down it along an axis line. This axis line is unique for a given spiral. You seem to understand how it's created but I don't follow about the "similar matrix to A".

Comment: A matrix similar to $A$ would be a matrix with the same eigenvalues.  That is $a+bi, a-bi, c$.  The axis will be parallel to the eigenvector associated with $c$ through the point of collapse.

Comment: Does your answer explain how to solve for the unique A that runs through the spiral? I'm not trying to use any random A. Each spiral has a line that runs through it. There's some relationship between the initial transform that makes the spiral and that line.

Comment: It should.  Post an example with your initial conditions and perturbations, and we can see how to solve for this axis.

Comment: I see. I guess I don't understand how to do what your solution is asking me to do. Say the initial conditions are Position: $x = 1, y = 0.25, z = 1.5$ Rotation: $x = -20, y = -30, z = -35$ and $k = 0.8$ I don't need to know the details of every step—a pseudo code algorithm would be enough.

The rotation is in XYZ Euler where it spins about the X axis.